# java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery(). 23

Tags: java, mysql, database, sql-update

I have problem with my Programs . Help me please.

> java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String path = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampledb";
String Username = "root";
String Password = ""; 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(path, Username, Password);
Statement s = con.createStatement();

String rGanTz = "UPDATE info SET Firstname = '"+txt_Firstname.getText()+"', Lastname = '"+txt_Lastname.getText()+"', Contact = '"+txt_Contact.getText()+"', WHERE '"+txt_Edpno.getText()+"'=EDPNO";
s.executeQuery(rGanTz);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data has been successfully Updated","Update file", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,null);
```

Comment: For `UPDATE` statement use [`executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `executeQuery`

Comment: Grumble. It's 2014. It's been the year of the cybercriminal every year now since about 2006. Why do people still write sql-injectable code? Please consider using prepared statements and bind parameters.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really consider what @OllieJones says in the comments about using prepared statements. @Rimas already gave you the solution so I will simply provide an example:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(path, Username, Password);

String rGanTz = "UPDATE info SET Firstname = ?, Lastname = ?, Contact = ? " + 
                "WHERE EDPNO = ?";

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(rGanTz);
ps.setString(1, txt_Firstname.getText());
ps.setString(2, txt_Lastname.getText());
ps.setString(3, txt_Contact.getText());
ps.setString(4, txt_Edpno.getText());

ps.executeUpdate();
```